Spontaneous symmetry breaking versus degenerate excitations in gapless quantum systems
I am trying to understand the difference between ground-state degeneracy induced by spontaneous breaking of a symmetry in the thermodynamic limit (system size $N\rightarrow \infty$) for a gapless Hamiltonian, and degeneracy caused by closing of a gap on top of a unique ground state.
For concreteness I will consider spin chains on lattices of dimension 1 or 2. I understand spontaneous symmetry breaking to be the collection of the following phenomena:

Ground state degeneracy occurs as $N\rightarrow \infty$ with degenerate ground states related by action of the broken symmetry.

The tunneling amplitude between the (thermodynamic limit) degenerate ground states is exponentially suppressed in the system size so that the symmetric superposition is unstable.

Related to 2., An infinitesimal symmetry breaking field (for example, $\sum_i h Z_i$ in the Transverse field Ising model with ZZ interactions) breaks the symmetry, choosing one of the degenerate ground states. Equivalently, the limits $N\rightarrow \infty$ and $h\rightarrow 0^+$ do not commute.


First, consider the 1D spin $1/2$ Antiferromagnetic Quantum Heisenberg Chain. From the Lieb Schultz Mattis theorem, it is known that the ground state for any finite $N$ is an $SU(2)$ singlet, and that the excitations are spinons with a gap that vanishes as $O(N^{-1})$. The 1D Heisenberg Antiferromagnet is not typically referred to as breaking the $SU(2)$ symmetry spontaneously, although the spinon excited states become 'degenerate' with the ground state in the thermodynamic limit, and the spinons form $SU(2)$ multiplets which break the symmetry by definition. In fact, Coleman's theorem states that spontaneous breaking of a continuous symmetry is not possible in 1D even at zero temperature, so in that sense the 1D Heisenberg AFM ground state cannot break the SU(2) symmetry. How do I interpret this though, if there are degenerate non-symmetric (spinon) states for an infinite system?
In contrast, now consider the 2D spin 1/2 Heisenberg Antiferromagnet on a square lattice. This system is known to spontaneously break the $SU(2)$ symmetry in the thermodynamic limit, forming a (degenerate) Neél ordered ground state. The ground state at any finite system size is known to be an $SU(2)$ singlet. Moreover, the 2D system is also known to have a gap vanishing as $O(N^-1)$. However, in this case, we interpret the Neél ordered ground state as being some superposition of many nearly degenerate symmetry breaking states in the 'tower' of excited states. However, we do not have the same interpretation for the 1D Heisenberg chain, i.e we do not have degenerate ground states that are symmetry breaking superpositions of spinon states even as the gap closes.
What is the fundamental difference between these two examples and what is the theoretical framework for understanding this difference? Why is the 2D case considered SSB while the 1D model is not? In both cases, it seems like symmetry breaking excited states become degenerate with the ground state as $N\rightarrow \infty$. Please note that I am not asking why the 1D Heisenberg Antiferromagnet does not have Goldstone modes - I am wondering why this is not considered symmetry breaking in the first place.

EDIT: I have added more background and clarification to my previous answer:
Let's first set a common ground: All eigenstates of the $SU(2)$ symmetric Heisenberg model can be chosen to be symmetric, because of the commutation $[H_\text{Heis}, \textbf{S}^2_\text{tot}] = [H_\text{Heis}, S^z_\text{tot}] = 0$, such that every eigenstate can be written as a multiplet $| S, m_z, \alpha \rangle$, with well-defined total spin $S$, total spin in $z$-direction $m_z$ and label $\alpha$ distinguishing between multiplets with the same ($S, m_z$). (I have borrowed the definition from [1]).

The 1D Heisenberg Antiferromagnet is not typically referred to as breaking the SU(2) symmetry spontaneously, although the spinon excited states become 'degenerate' with the ground state in the thermodynamic limit, and the spinons form SU(2) multiplets which break the symmetry by definition.


1D Heisenberg AFM ground state cannot break the SU(2) symmetry. How do I interpret this though, if there are degenerate non-symmetric (spinon) states for an infinite system?

As you correctly pointed out, the antiferromagentic (AF) Heisenberg chain is gapless and does not show spontaneous symmetry breaking (SSB) for any temperature, including $T = 0$. However, with the above definition I gave for multiplets the statement "the spinons form SU(2) multiplets which break the symmetry by definition" is contradictory. Even if we have different kinds of definition for a multiplet, the spinons (as derived through the Bethe ansatz) do not break the symmetry by definition (e.g. have a look at [2] for an overview on how to derive the excitations).

In both cases [1d and 2d AF Heisenberg], it seems like symmetry breaking excited states become degenerate with the ground state as $N \to \infty$.

I believe, this misunderstanding comes from mixing gapless magnons/spinons with the "Anderson tower of states". Generally, the tower of states (which are explicitely not the individual magnon/spinon excitations) collapse as $\Delta E _\text{tower} \sim 1/N$ with the groundstate, where $N = L^d$ and $L$ the system length and $d$ the dimension, whereas the excitations (magnons/spinons) become gapless as $\Delta E _\text{exc} \sim 1/L$. This is true for both the 1d and 2d system (although this has not been rigorously proven [3], the physical picture should hold as highlighted by the Lieb-Mattis model [4]). The huge difference comes from the different scalings, such that for $d > 1$-dimensional systems the excitations, because of the slower scaling, "do not influence the groundstate manifold in the thermodynamic limit" [4]. One way to think of it is to consider the quantum fluctuations/corrections on top of the classical Néel state. In 2d the Néel state is stabilised (see your third point) due to the "tower of states" which are separated from the excitations, whereas in 1d the excitations (the quantum fluctuations) are on equal footing with the "tower of states" and thus destabilize the symmetry broken Néel state.
EDIT: addressing OP's comment
To better get a feeling for the "Andersons Tower of states", I can recommend the related post First excited states of the Heisenberg model on a bipartite lattice/graph aswell as [5], which is a general but detailed introduction to sponatenous symmetry breaking (SSB), [4], which discusses as a toy model for SSB the Lieb-Mattis model and highlights the first signs of the "tower of states" and especially [3], which is a more mathematical/rigorous discussion of SSB and long range order and the emergence of the "tower of states".
Contrary to the "tower of states" the magnon/spinon excitation are created by modifying the symmetry-broken (for SSB, i.e. 2d AF Heisenberg)/symmetric (w/o SSB, i.e. 1d AF Heisenberg) ground state. To highlight the weirdness of SSB in the 2d case, the magnon excitation for finite $L$ are not exact energy eigenstates but become so only in the thermodynamic limit, where the groundstate spontaneously breaks the symmetry (ferromagnets are "special" and should not be taken as a paradigmatic example of SSB; see [5], Exercise 2.7). Therefore, "physical" magnons are also symmetry-broken states.
Because quantum fluctuations stabilise the symmetric state for the 1d AF Heisenberg model, the spinon excitations that are build on top of it are themselves symmetric. Generally there is no immediate reason to expect SSB for the excitations (especially because they are gapless). Many sources online discuss further in detail why the 1d AF Heisenberg model does not display SSB.
Although the absence of SSB in one dimension is not uncommon, it is in 2d. One example would be Quantum Spin Liquids which display many exotic properties not only in its ground state but also in its excitations. But detecing such phases with symmetric groundstates which are stabilised by quantum fluctuations are very difficult to detect.
References:
[1] (lecture notes) Symmetries II: Non-Abelian
[2] Introduction to the Bethe Ansatz II
[3] Long-range order, “tower” of states, and symmetry breaking in lattice quantum systems
[4]  Studying Continuous Symmetry Breaking with Exact Diagonalization
[5] An Introduction to Spontaneous Symmetry Breaking

Thank you so much, I think this almost answers my question - I do think that the root of my question is what the difference is between spinon states and the anderson tower states. I have a few follow ups: by multiplet, I mean an irrep with dimension > 1. Then, there are basis states in each irrep that do not respect the symmetry (but you can form symmetric superpositions of them). Is the point that spinons are precisely in such symmetric superpositions? Why are they stable (in line with my points 2. and 3. above)?
